# How to properly integrate server-side datatable with Angular 6

Tags: angular, datatables

My `DataTable` is having this issue where all of the functionalities like search, pagination, sorting etc are not working.

It's just straight-up showing all the data from the API call:

[image: sample table]

[image: sample_table2]

**Code:**

`my-table.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { MyTable } from './my-table';

const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable()
export class MyTableService {

  private myTableUrl = 'http://my-api-call/my-tables';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getMyTables (): Observable<MyTable[]> {

    return this.http.get<MyTable[]>(this.myTableUrl);
  }
}
```

`my-table.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { MyTable } from './my-table';
import { MyTableService } from './my-table.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-table',
  templateUrl: './my-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-table.component.css'],
  providers: [MyTableService]
})
export class MyTablesComponent implements OnInit {

    myTables: MyTable[];

    constructor(private myTableService: MyTableService) { }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.getMyTables();
    }

    getMyTables(): void {
        this.myTableService.getMyTables()
        .subscribe(myTables => this.myTables = myTables);
    }

}
```

`my-table.ts`

```
export class MyTable {
    id: number;
    tp_name: string;
    tp_location: string;
    flag: number;
    creation_date: string;
    created_by: string;
    update_date: string;
    updated_by: string;
    error: string;
}
```

`my-table.component.html`

```
<table id="my-tables" datatable class="table table-borderless table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Flag</th>
            <th>Creation Date</th>
            <th>Created By</th>
            <th>Update Date</th>
            <th>Updated By</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngIf="myTables?.length != 0">
        <tr *ngFor="let myTable of myTables">
            <td>{{ myTable.tp_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ myTable.tp_location }}</td>
            <td>{{ myTable.flag }}</td>
            <td>{{ myTable.creation_date }}</td>
            <td>{{ myTable.created_by }}</td>
            <td>{{ myTable.update_date }}</td>
            <td>{{ myTable.updated_by }}</td>
            <td class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody *ngIf="myTables?.length == 0">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" class="no-data-available">No data found!</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

my styles and scripts:

```
"styles": [
  "src/styles.css",
  "node_modules/admin-lte/bower_components/datatables.net-bs/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css",
  "node_modules/admin-lte/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
  "node_modules/admin-lte/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "node_modules/admin-lte/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css",
  "node_modules/admin-lte/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css"
],
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/admin-lte/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "node_modules/admin-lte/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
  "node_modules/admin-lte/dist/js/adminlte.min.js",
  "node_modules/admin-lte/bower_components/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js",
  "node_modules/admin-lte/bower_components/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
  "node_modules/admin-lte/bower_components/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"
]
```

The functionalities work when I call for just a regular JSON file for example: `private myTableUrl = 'path/to/my-table.json';`.

I think this is a problem with Angular itself and `DataTable`.

Note: I'm still learning Angular. Any corrections and solutions are very much appreciated.

Comment: @Nasiruddin Saiyed can you give an example? I can't seem to get your point.

Comment: YEEEEEEEEEESSSSSSSS!!!!!! IT WORKED!!! Thanks a lot! :D
Please put that as an answer so I can mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: BTW, Do you also know how to remove the sorting function in my **Actions** column?

Comment: For it you need to share how did you setup data table implementation, its Directive  or you have implemented using jQuery.

Comment: All I did was the above code to use `DataTable` in my project. I have imported `DataTable` in my `app.component.ts` and call it in `my-table.component.html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because table is rendering first then data is loaded after api call, simple i did was using *ngIf and hide table until data is not fetched then it will load correctlyt. Its just an experimental.

```
<table id="my-tables" datatable class="table table-borderless table-hover" *ngIf="myTable">
```

Happy coding!!!.